# Употребление НЕГО/НЕЕ

Tags: грамматика

Здравствуйте! Пожалуйста, подскажите, как верно: "Если  наша любовь - это рассказ, то конец у НЕЕ грустный" или "Если наша любовь - это рассказ, то конец у НЕГО грустный". Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ПРАВИЛЬНО: "Если наша любовь - это рассказ, то конец у НЕГО грустный".

Первый вариант не подходит, так как семантика неверна: получается, что у любви грустный конец не сам по себе, а только если считать ее  рассказом.

Comment: София, спасибо, что всегда помогаете!

Answer (score 2):

Хороший вопрос.
Я  не возражаю категорически против сказанного Софьей, но не столь категоричен. 
Естественнее, конечно, в этой фразе грамматически идет речь о конце рассказа, то разве нельзя говорить о конце именно любви? Как некий стилистический прием - уж точно.
Так что и второй вариант ("у неё") грамматически допустим.

"Если ты думаешь, что литература - твое призвание, то **она** - нелегкий хлеб".
Пример сконструированный, искать у классиков некогда.

[[@София](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)!
Что Вам не понравилось в моей фразе, не очень понимаю.
Оно касалось грамматики. Можете заменить литературу на спорт и и.д.
Смысл был в том, что совершенно необязательно требовать принадлежности свойства или сравнительной характеристики подобию (рассказ), а не прообразу (любовь).  
Во всяком случае - это как минимум авторское право, если здравому смыслу не протворечит.

Если наша любовь станет дворцом,то у неё будет счастливый конец.
Если наша любовь станет дворцом,то у него будет золотой купол.

А у нас -Что Вам не понравилось в моей фразе, не очень понимаю.
Оно касалось грамматики. Можете заменить "литературу" на "спорт" и т.д.
Смысл был в том, что совершенно необязательно требовать принадлежности свойства или сравнительной характеристики подобию (рассказ), а не прообразу (любовь).  
Во всяком случае - это как минимум авторское право, если здравому смыслу не противоречит.

Если наша любовь станет дворцом,то у неё будет счастливый конец.
Если наша любовь станет дворцом,то у него будет золотой купол.

А у нас - фраза, может быть подобна обоим этим примерам. В зависимости от вкладываемого автором смысла. Согласен, Ваша трактовка - более естественна. Но не более. Нельзя решать за автора.

Простите, возникли технические проблемы - мне надо срочно менять клавиатуру.

Comment: А я категорически возражаю против Вашего сконструированного предложения. Литература не потому нелегкий хлеб, что кто-то считает ее своим призванием, а сама по себе нелегка.А Ваше предложение надо переделать: "Если ты думаешь, что литература - твое призвание, и собираешься всерьёз ею заняться, то имей в виду, что, она - нелегкий хлеб".

Comment: София, тысячу и оно извинение, меня вылетело **не**, что изменило смысл фразы на противоположный. Я, наоборот, хотел сказать, что в целом с Вами согласен, но есть одно некатегоричное замечание.  
Это по форме.  

По сути - в тексте основного ответа.